# Add product to cart with URL slug Woocommerce sends me directly to checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, url, woocommerce

I want to add a product to cart from a URL slug, I found a common proper way default by Woocommerce to achieve this. But unfortunately the URL send me directly to the checkoutpage. I also changed settings in Woocommerce to disable send me to cart.

```
https://example.com/page-slug/?add-to-cart=25&quantity=1
```

and tried

```
https://example.com/page-slug/?add-to-cart=25
```

Does someone have any idea what goes wrong. This is the source:

Comment: You need to disable from settings, the checkout redirection on add to cart…

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying on me, I did disabled that option! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem by adding the following code to my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_redirect_function' );
    function custom_redirect_function() {
    return get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( '#' ) );
}
```

Comment: You should simply use instead `add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', '__return_false');`.